# Teradata MAX function

Tags: teradata

Which row will be return if we use following function?

```
 MAX (NAME)
```

Where we have following two rows in name column

```
1 ABC
2 ABC
```

Answer (score 3):

Neither. An aggregate will be returned that is not tied to either row, but rather the `Max(Name)` value, which will obviously have to be `ABC` as it's the only value available:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE test
(
    f1 INTEGER,
    f2 CHAR(3)
) PRIMARY INDEX (f1) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'ABC');

SELECT MAX(f2) FROM test;

DROP TABLE test;
```

Which just returns `ABC`

You can think of it this way. If I write the number `2` on a whiteboard and ask you to say out loud which one is the largest, you will say *"2"*; it would be silly to ask *"Which 'two' did you pick though?"*.

Comment: @SantoshSuplepatil - Why don’t you try and see for yourself? You will find that it returns the same as `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM test;`

Comment: Right. The Case will first run producing an intermediate result set that contains both 1 and 2. Then the `Max()` will hit and take `2` and return that.

Answer (score 0):

Since both the values are same and there are only two row,You will get the output as "ABC" when you try to find the max