# Teradata MAX function with duplicate rows

Tags: teradata

Which value will be return if we use following function and why?

MAX (CASE WHEN NAME='ABC' THEN GENDER END) AS SEX

Where we have following two rows in table

```
GENDER        NAME
      M                ABC
      F                 ABC
```

Comment: It's not returning a row, it's returning a value.

Comment: Yes..tell me which value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Teradata MAX function with duplicate row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318683/teradata-max-function-with-duplicate-row)

Comment: @SantoshSuplepatil Run this yourself in your system. This would be a simple one to test. The answer though is `M` as `M` is greater than `F` and both our `ABC`.

Comment: So, do u mean it will give seq no to letters A-Z as 1-26??

Comment: Because `Gender` is non-numeric it will use [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) to determine the sorting/max. It will output, literally an `M`. It's just sorting, just as it would with an `SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY gender`

Comment: This is a bit strange. Do you not have access to Teradata? Questions for Stack Overflow are usually "How can I do X?" not "What happens if I do X?". Just do it and see.

Comment: @Error_2646 I know the answer but I had doubt why M was returned and now doubt is cleared by JNEVILL

Answer (score 2):

Here is the test you can run in your own system (Teradata studio, SQL Assistant, Atanasuite, bteq, or whatever you use):

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE test2
(
    f1 CHAR(1),
    f2 CHAR(3)
) PRIMARY INDEX (f1) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ('M', 'ABC');
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ('F', 'ABC');

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN f2='ABC' THEN f1 END) FROM test2;

DROP TABLE test2;
```

This will output `M`

What is happening is that BEFORE aggregation an intermediate result set is being generated of all rows for column `f1`. That one column is being set to whatever the value is in `f1` or NULL depending on your CASE statement:

Intermediate Result Set:

```
col1
-----
M
F
```

Both rows return something since both have a `Name` equal to `ABC`. Now we take the `Max()` as that's the next step in this SQL's order of operations.

The Max of the two values `M` and `F` is: `M` because `M` is higher in the alphabet (lexicographical sort).

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! Lexicographical sorting can be a head scratcher sometimes. Especially when you get into alphanumerics like `M0123`,`M9`,`MA1`... which one would be `Max()` then?  ;)

Comment: I think it should be MA1

Comment: You know more than you let on!